# "Will make and will continue" or " will make and continue"

Tags: usage, verb-forms

The Group will make strategic move to strengthen its market shares and will continue to invest in product design and development.

Can I omit the second "will" and write as:-

The Group will make strategic move to strengthen its market shares and continue to invest in product design and development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omitting the second *will* changes the meaning.

The original says that

```
The group 1. will make strategic moves to strengthen its market shares
      and 2. will continue to invest in product design and development.
```

There are two actions: *making a move* and *continuing to invest*

But with the second version you get this:

```
The group will make strategic moves to 1. strengthen its market shares
                                   and 2. continue to invest in product design and development.
```

There is only one action, *making a move*, with two purposes: *strengthening market shares* and *continuing to invest*.

Comment: but if we think of parallelism, cannot it be written that way?

Comment: @MaulikV Without the second *will*, the parallelism is between *strengthen...* and *continue...*, not *make...* and *continue....* If what you mean is that the Group will make moves to continue investing, you not only can but should write it the second way. If that's not what you mean, you should not write it that way. To make both *make...* and *continue...* complements of *will* you need to cast *strengthen...* as something other than an infinitive - perhaps *will make moves towards higher share prices and continue to invest ...*

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. It follows the [rule of parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_%28grammar%29).

> The Group **will** make strategic move to strengthen its market shares. 
>  The Group **will** continue to invest in product design and development.

Can be written as...

> The Group will make strategic move to strengthen its market shares and continue to invest in product design and development.

[Good read here.](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/01/)